# Get Voice Memos from iPhone or MacOS to Apple Watch

Tags: icloud, apple-watch, voice-memo

I saw a lot of questions and answers related to how to show the recorded sound files from Apple Watch in other devices like iPhone, MacOS, and also syncing via cloud.

However, I want to ask the opposite:

Is it possible to record a voice-memo in iPhone or in MacOS, and to see/play that recording file from within the Apple Watch?

Currently I see only the "Watch Recordings" folder's content when I open the Voice Memos app in Apple Watch. Of course everything is synchronized in cloud.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to record a voice-memo in iPhone or in MacOS, and to see/play that recording file from within the Apple Watch?

### Yes, by manually sending the recording to your Apple Watch via Mail

1. On your ***iPhone***, open the (Apple) [**Watch**](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/watch/id1069511734) app.
2. Go to My Watch > Mail > **Include Mail**.
3. Now, go to My Watch > Mail > **Accounts** and select the account.s on which you want to send your recording (the one.s you want, doesn't matter).
4. Then, once this is set up, open the **Voice Memos** app on your iPhone.
5. Click on the recording (the name of it) you want to listen on your Apple Watch, it should show the play bar and the play button as well as some other options.

[image: the three-dots]

6. Then, click on the **three-dots** at the top-right-corner of the recording, this should open a "Share"-like menu.
7. Now, choose either (1) Save to Files, (2) Copy, (3) Share.

[image: Share-like menu with (1), (2) and (3) made clear]

8.1. *The following steps will be if you chose (1) **Save to Files***.

8.1.a When you click on Save to Files, it should show a pop-up window asking you where you want to save the file (as .mp4), choose the place where you want it to be and tap "**Save**" (top-right-corner).

8.1.b Now, still on your iPhone, open **Mail** app and **compose** an email to the associated email address (the one you associated to your Apple Watch).

8.1.c For the email body, put whatever you want but at some point, click on the **document symbol** (on top of the letter "i" on your (built-in) keyboard), this should make the same pop-up window with Files view.

8.1.d Choose the file you've just imported to Files, it will automatically include it in the email body.

8.1.e Once, you're happy with your result, tap on **send**.

8.2 *The following steps will be if you chose (2) **Copy***.

8.2.a Once you have clicked on Copy, the file (.mp4) will be *copied to your clipboard*. Open **Mail** app.

8.2.b Now, still on your iPhone (in Mail), **compose** an email to the associated email address (the one you associated to your Apple Watch).

8.2.c Then, click on the cursor (blue pointer indicating where you are typing), it should show a menu on top of it, click on **Paste**. This should paste the whole .mp4 file into the email body.

8.2.d Once, you're happy with your result, tap on **send**.

8.3 *The following steps will be if you chose (3) **Share***.

8.3.a Once you've tapped on Share, a menu proposing apps will appear in the same dialog window (where the options are). Click on **Mail**.

8.3.b It should open up a composing email with the *recording (as .mp4 file) in the body*. Write the associated email address (the one you associated to your Apple Watch) as the person you're sending the recording to.

8.3.c Once, you're happy with your result, tap on **send**.

9. Once this sharing by Mail process is done, on your ***Apple Watch***, open **Mail** app.
10. (You may need to reload the inbox to see the email with the attachement) Open the email and tap on the .mp4 file (in the body).
11. Now, you can press play and listen to it.

**Note** : you can also skip steps `8.1.c` and `8.1.d` by : (Opening Mail app, clicking on the compose button - that's in step `8.1.b`) going to Files app and click-and-hold on the .mp4 file you've just imported, then (keep you finger pressed), with another finger, re-open Mail and dropping the file in the body of the email being composed.

**Note 2** : For more information about steps `8.1.c` and `8.1.d`, I propose you read this Apple Support article about how to [Add email attachments in Mail on iPhone](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/iphone/iph8580f163b/ios).

**Note 3** : *This answer is assuming you are using Apple Watch Ultra running watchOS 9*. This is sure to work on that version but it is highly probable to work on oldest ones (watchOS 6-later).

For more information about using Mail in Apple Watch, I suggest you consult [this](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/watch-ultra/apd29461a7b7/watchos) Apple Support article.

Comment: Note that it is also possible through other (third-party) services such as Google Drive.

Comment: I mean, to play the original file, by syncing/cloud, and not to copy it. I want to use the same file (just as it possible the other direction)

Comment: @Cocktail Oh, you mean that you want to play it from Voice Memos on your watch?

Comment: yes why its not possible?

Comment: @Cocktail No, unfortunately not. It is not possible yet but you can follow the steps given in the answer for an alternative or [propose the feature](https://www.apple.com/feedback/watch/).

Comment: Both will take too much time but thanks a lot. Easier to develop an alternative

Comment: @Cocktail As you say then :)

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when I re-paired my watch. My recordings never sync'd back to the watch from restoring the backup.

Old school mix-tape solution. I went to a quiet corner of the room, pressed record on the Apple Watch and press play on the iPhone. Of course it duplicates the recordings back to the phone & the quality will be slighly degraded - but worked for my purpose.

I feel it's a bug - if the recordings are in the 'Apple Watch' folder on the phone then they should sync back to the watch.